# Scrip sample file? to connect sharepoint 2013 and sql server in a form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, sharepoint-server, sql-server

I want to create a template in sharepoint 2013 and connected to an SQL server table, so it will populate with the info entered in a form.

Comment: You mean you want to enter data into SQL via a Form in SharePoint?

Comment: yes! using SharePoint designer 2013, InfoPath, etc? the best method for ease to use.

Answer (score 0):

The "proper" way to do this is with Business Connectivity Services (BCS). BCS can be a bit heavy handed if your needs are for a periodic one way sync of a single list.

Does it have to be real-time? The path of least resistance would be a scheduled SSIS package leveraging the SharePoint List Connector available here:
http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652

Detailed usage examples here:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/2/0/D20E1C5F-72EA-4505-9F26-FEF9550EFD44/SharePoint%20SSIS%20Adapters%202011.docx

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easier option is to use External Content Type (Which points to SQL table) and use it to create External List. In this case you don't need to develop anything.

After creating External List you can customize the forms.

Comment: how would i point the External Content Type to an SQL table? could u please explain this procedure in a video or something. I have tried but I am not able to create a form so it can populate into a SQL table

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220063.aspx

Comment: that doesn't explain.. how to a form is created and have the data populated in the SQL table.